# Silent sessions on sql alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to apply actions to a db session without getting the printouts of the underlying SQL statements. Is that possible?

```
    engine = create_engine(dbaddress)
    Base = declarative_base()
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    s = self.DBSession()
    person = Person(person_id = 1, name = "david")
    s.merge(person)
    s.commit()
```

without getting the long printout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `echo` flag to `False` (or simply leave it out) in `create_engine`:

```
engine = create_engine(dbaddress)  # echo defaults to False
```

The [echo flag](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#connecting) sets up SQLAlchemy logging, which means that you will see all the SQL that is generated.